# I need to pull info from several workbooks into one table on a master workbook using Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, power, query

I am using Excel 2016 and I need to solve a problem. I have multiple businesses that have to log unique transactions for approval. Each location has an excel workbook that they update daily with these transactions then they get sent to me. I want the info from all the sheets to automatically pull and combine to a master workbook when refreshed so that I can approve all in one sheet. I have done this using power query but when I refresh it adds the old data again each time I refresh. I want it to be a running list without duplicating what has already been pulled. Not sure if there is a better/easier way to accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an incremental data load with Power Query, as described in this post: http://ms-olap.blogspot.co.nz/2015/05/incremental-data-loads-in-microsoft.html

Conceptually, you use one query for the initial data load. Then create another query that loads data from the new source and appends that to the data from the first query. More details in the linked article.